# PHP: Can we return inside Try block

Tags: php

In some cases I don't care if Query fails or for example something === 1 , in both cases I want to `return FALSE or die() etc...`, so i do the following:

```
function test($db){
  try
  {
     $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     // If Query fails, PDO itself will throw exception,
     // but i also check the value here and throw exception if it's not !== 1

     if ($stmt['column'] === 1)
     {
        throw new PDOException('Wrong Column Info');
     }
     else
     {
        return TRUE;
     }
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
     return FALSE;
  }
}
```

My question is, is it okay that I'm using `throw new PDOException` or should i use `Exception` instead of `PDOException` and then catch Exception too?

Comment: It's fine to use `PDOException`

Comment: why bother throwing anything if you're just going to catch everything and return false? Just return false if the if() test fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be answered so many ways. Your way works but could be made a little clearer.

Here would be my take:

```
function test($db){
  try
  {
     $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     // If Query fails, PDO itself will throw exception,
     // but i also check the value here and throw exception if it's not !== 1

     if ($stmt['column'] === 1)
     {
        throw new PDOException('Wrong Column Info');
     }

     return true;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
     error_log("Query failed!");
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this return TRUE even if PDO query fails?

Comment: No because throwing an exception is going to halt execution there and goto the catch section

Comment: @Ara, no, the try block would stop as soon as the query issues a PDOException.

Comment: I had a major "WTF no way" moment with that when a co-worker pointed it out... don't sweat it man :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Trying this code out should have told you that.

However, you don't need to.  This would accomplish the same thing.  Either way is fine, I'm just pointing this out.

```
function test($db){
  try
  {
     $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     // If Query fails, PDO itself will throw exception,
     // but i also check the value here and throw exception if it's not !== 1

     if ($stmt['column'] === 1)
     {
        throw new PDOException('Wrong Column Info');
     }
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
     return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tested it, but i was wondering if it is correct way.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a single correct way to this.  There are a lot of ways this could be written to accomplish the same thing.